# Insufficient Privileges coming on Record Type for Admin profile

Tags: record-type, insufficient-privileges

I'm having a difficult time figuring this out.

Ran the below snippet in Anonymous:

```
 RecordType rt = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE Name='RecordType_Name'];
 System.debug(rt);
```

Now, when I put the id in url i get an Insufficient Privileges Error. I'm on system administrator profile . Have checked that the record type is already made available for Sys Admin profile, also I'm able to create an Opportunity of the same record type.

Could somebody tell me as to what could be the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Record type is not directly accessible with given format. 
 www.instanceurl.com/recordTypeId

Instead you have to use the below format.

https://www.instanceurl.com/setup/ui/recordtypefields.jsp?id={!RecordTypeID}

eg. If my instance URL is "https://pranayDev-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/"

and my recordTypeId is 012B0000000Llf8 ,

Then my record type URL will be : "https://pranayDev-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/setup/ui/recordtypefields.jsp?id=012B0000000Llf8"

Thanks.

Comment: Is this is the way accessing record types work since long ago? Can't we access it directly via: www.instanceurl.com/recordTypeId? If so, why? Also is there any documentation/resources supporting this answer?

Comment: It has been since start. There is no documentation to state this. Almost all setup objects are designed this way.